# Screen scale cannot be set

Tags: settings, hdpi

In wayland, I can set the screen scaling of my monitor (connected to RX580 GPU with amdgpu driver) to 200% just fine.

However, I had to switch back to X11, because one of my apps (FlashPrint) will not work under xwayland.

When running X11, the screen scale went back to 100% and I cannot change it to 200%.

My hardware has not changed. Just the display server: from XWayland to Xorg.

[image]

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel AlderLake-S GT1 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-3: Logitech BRIO Ultra HD Webcam type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid,uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8 driver: X:
    loaded: amdgpu,modesetting unloaded: fbdev,radeon,vesa dri: iris
    gpu: amdgpu,i915 resolution: 1: 3840x2160~60Hz 2: 1280x768~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.2 renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 770
    (ADL-S GT1)
```